# WPF C# Change background color of textblock in radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf

would be greatful if someone could help me out with my issue, due to my limited experience with WPF.

I have some radiobuttons which have transparent background at runtime. When a radiobutton is clicked I want to change the backgroundcolor.

I have already gone thorugh [WPF Radio Button Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711535/wpf-radio-button-background-color) but did not find the solution.

At the moment it looks something like this;

```xml
<RadioButton x:Name="rdButtonOption1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,241,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="85" Width="453" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Checked="rdButtonOption1_Checked">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="85" Width="430">
            <TextBlock Name="txtBlockBtn1" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.541"/>
        </Border>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

```cs
private void rdButtonOption1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new BrushConverter();

    txtBlockBtn1.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FFBDFFB3");

    rdButtonOption2.IsChecked = false;
    rdButtonOption3.IsChecked = false;
    rdButtonOption4.IsChecked = false;

    MarkCorrectAnswer();
    DisableRadioButtons();          
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background of "Text" or "Button"

Comment: Preferably the button.

Answer (score 0):

The link of your have should works for your case, no matter you want to change the background color of `Text` or `Button`, try following code to see which color part you want to change for the background

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Temporary Sets" Background="Red" Foreground="White" Width="500">
            <RadioButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Green">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Brown"
                             Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="Checked" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Label Margin="5 0 0 0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Checked" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RadioButton.Template>
        </RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Background` of the `Border` or `TextBlock` or both:

```
private void rdButtonOption1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

    Border border = rb.Content as Border;
    if (border != null)
        border.Background = Brushes.Red;

    txtBlockBtn1.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: @CodeKiller: What didn't work? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set a color to the background area of the radiobutton, so that the text is present over the backgroundcolor. Clear enough?

Comment: The text is present over over `TextBlock` and the `Border` so setting the background of any of these will make the text appear on a background. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: The `TextBlock` has no text in it in your example.

Comment: Text is generated from DB at runtime, so that is not a problem.

"The text is present over over TextBlock and the Border so setting the background of any of these will make the text appear on a background. Isn't this what you want? "

Yes correct thats what I want.

Comment: Then my solution should work. Coud you post a picture of what you are currently seeing please?