# WPF : while radio button is selected MouseOver does not work

Tags: c#, wpf

this my radio button's Trigger it do not work but other Trigger while unselect it's work,

i m new to the WPF

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RED"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [WPF Radio Button Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711535/wpf-radio-button-background-color)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: so kind of you. thanks The problem is the template for the radiobutton already has another MultiTrigger,  it will therefore over-ride the value this MultiTrigger

Comment: You are welcome! :) Next time please try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question.